# Can't install p5-Digest-SHA1 on FreeBSD 8.3

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to instasll `rkhunter` on a FreeBSD 8.3 box. However, during `make install` one of the dependencies failed to build:

```
===>  Building package for p5-Digest-SHA1-2.13
Creating package /usr/ports/security/p5-Digest-SHA1/work/p5-Digest-SHA1-2.13.tbz
Registering depends:.
Creating bzip'd tar ball in '/usr/ports/security/p5-Digest-SHA1/work/p5-Digest-SHA1-2.13.tbz'
tar: lib/perl5/5.10/man/man3/Digest::SHA1.3.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/mach/Digest/SHA1.pm: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/mach/auto/Digest/SHA1/.packlist: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/mach/auto/Digest/SHA1/SHA1.bs: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/mach/auto/Digest/SHA1/SHA1.so: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
pkg_create: make_dist: tar command failed with code 256
```

Any ideas how I may be able to fix this?

Comment: Start by posting the actual errors.

Comment: please post the output of the staging phase.